# Dropwdownlist as filter for mutliselect

Tags: sharepoint-2013, multi-select, dropdownbox

I have to do the following in SharePoint but I'm new to SharePoint.
On my screen I have a dropdownlist with businessunits.
I also have a multiselect with products.

Now when I select a businessunit in the dropdown, I need to display the corresponding products in the multiselect.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: with javascript or serverside?

Comment: @Legends: I wanted to do it with Javascript.

Comment: check this link how to retrieve data from sp list:
http://www.plusconsulting.com/blog/2013/05/crud-on-list-items-using-rest-services-jquery/

What is ur concrete problem? How to retireve the data from sp or how to build the multi select? you wanna do it with jquery or with postback?

Comment: @Legends: I want to link my dropdown with my multiselect, so that the values in the multiselect are filtered.

Comment: u didn't answer my question...

Comment: @Legends: sorry, guess I posted to quickly. I need to know how I can bind my multiselect to my dropdown, so that when I select a value in de dropdown, the multiselect gets filtered. If possible I would do it with javascript.

Comment: with jquery or pure javascript?

Comment: @Legends: it has to be done on a page on SharePoint, so i would do it in pure javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, btw I don't how the controls are rendered in SP, but this works at least in chrome.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/kowove/1/edit?html,js,console,output)